# Which visa should I apply for if I need at least two entries to the Schengen area?

Tags: visas, schengen, croatia, schengen-visas

I hold an Indian passport and live in India.
I am planning to go to Croatia through France and then to Germany and go back to India through France again.
A double or mutiple entry Schengen Visa is required for Croatia.
Is it easier to get a Double entry Schengen visa than a multiple entry Schengen Visa for a first time tourist?

Comment: Do you plan to _enter_ France on the way to Croatia? (In fact, will you spend any time in France other than changing planes? If not you will be applying to Germany for the visa, not France.)

Comment: I will spend 2 days in France, 2 in Prague, 3 in Croatia, 4 in Italy, 2 in Germany and finally one in France again before the return flight. I didn’t mention Italy earlier because the itinerary wasn’t finalized. Now it is :)

Answer (score 4):

Double-entry visas are created exactly for itineraries like the one you describe, and is probably what you will get issued when you apply.  You can always *try* checking the box for requesting multiple entries, but it's unlikely you will get that as a first-time traveler -- unless you have an extremely good story why you would need to make *frequent* and *repeated* visits to the Schengen area in the future.

(Be aware that since you're planning to spend the longest time in Italy, you must apply for the visa at the Italian consulate, even though you're entering and leaving through France).

Comment: I was planning the same. Thank you for the confirmation.